# Control camera exposure via exposure control class

Tags: c#, .net, camera, uwp, media

I have a class in a uwp application that initializes a MediaCapture object with the device ID of a USB camera and then I call that class on the loading of the main page of my app which opens a preview stream.  Everything about that works just fine but I am trying to control the exposure of the camera via MediaCapture.VideoDeviceController which according to an MS Docs article should be possible via the Exposure Control Class.  However, when I try to implement the slider they show in that article, it says it is [not supported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93dfE.png) and throws a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`.  Now, I know this camera supports exposure control because I am able to adjust it in another application.  In addition to that, I can see through the "exposure" property above that, that it has the following [capabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwQIQ.png).  Those min and max values are the values I am able to see in the other application.  So, how am I able to adjust the exposure using the Exposure Control Class? Is there a better way of doing this? My end goal is to take an image using the camera and save it to a file.

camera class:

```
class Camera:ICamera
{
    public double exposure { get; set; }
    public MediaCapture media;
    public string deviceID;
    public async Task InitializeCamera()
    {
        var videoDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.VideoCapture);
        media = new MediaCapture();

        for (int i = 0; i < videoDevices.Count; i++)
        {
            var devInfo = videoDevices[i];
            if (devInfo.Name !="UNICAM Front" && devInfo.Name != "UNICAM Rear")
            {
                deviceID = devInfo.Id;
                break;
            }
        }
        await media.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings {VideoDeviceId = deviceID});
    }
}
```

page loading function:

```
private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Camera camera = new Camera();
    await camera.InitializeCamera();
    MediaCapture _media;
    _media = camera.media;
    bool _isPreviewing;

    DisplayRequest _displayRequest = new DisplayRequest();

    _displayRequest.RequestActive();
    DisplayInformation.AutoRotationPreferences = DisplayOrientations.Landscape;

    PreviewControl.Source = _media;
    await _media.StartPreviewAsync();
    _isPreviewing = true;   
}
```

Comment: We should be able to use the `ExposureControl.Supported` property to check if the capture device supports the exposure control. There is a [Manual camera controls sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/CameraManualControls), please refer it.